# Perfect forwarding in D?

Tags: d, perfect-forwarding

tl;dr: How do you do [perfect forwarding](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1385.htm) in D?

---

The link has a great explanation, but for example, let's say I have this method:

```
void foo(T)(in int a, out int b, ref int c, scope int delegate(ref const(T)) d)
    const nothrow
{
}
```

How do I create another method, `bar()`, which can be called in lieu of `foo()`, which subsequently calls `foo()` "perfectly" (i.e. without introducing compilation/scope/etc. problems at the calling site)?

The naive approach

```
auto bar(T...)(T args)
{
    writeln("foo() intercepted!");
    return foo(args);
}
```

of course doesn't work because it doesn't handle the `ref`, `in`, `out`, `inout`, the `const`-ness of the method, `pure`-ity, `nothrow`, etc... and it also limits how the values can be used with r-values.

And I don't know how to handle those possible cases... any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your naive approach can be improved upon, though it's still not perfect:

```
auto ref bar(T...)(auto ref T args)
{
    writeln("foo() intercepted!");
    return foo(args);
}
```

Now the only problem is `scope` arguments.

Comment: Wait, what about `nothrow`, `pure`, `const`, `inout`, `@property`, `@safe`, and all those other things I can't think of at the moment? Every one of those (even `@property`) can slightly change code behavior, and/or prevent compilation.

Comment: You need an auto ref as return, and an if considition to your template, and still, I'm not sure this is enough.

Comment: @Mehrdad:  Good points, although pure is inferred for templates nowadays.

Comment: @dsimcha : you need to test if foo is callable with args. Something passed by value to bar can be then passed by reference to foo. But the changed value will only be visible into bar which isn't what we want. Note that I'm not sure of that and may be wrong.